# Не работают Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V при запуске PowerShell с русской раскладкой

Tags: powershell

Если запускаю переключившись (Alt+Shift) на английский язык, то Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V работают. Если менять раскладку уже при запущенном PowerShell'e, то ничего не меняется. Пробовал удалять и обновлять PSReadLine. $profile не менял. Проблема возникает и в стандартном PowerShell'e Windows 10, и в pscore 6.2.4

Comment: Попробуйте использовать shift + insert

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Значит проблема в восприятии клавиш, решил так пока что так - https://pastebin.com/H2VRWCNw